# C#: copy dependency of dependency when building project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# project (e.g. Project.exe) which depends on a.dll, and a.dll depends on b.dll.

When I build Project.exe, a.dll gets built and copied into the output folder for Project.exe - but b.dll does not get copied over into the output folder.

How can I get both a.dll AND b.dll copied into Project.exe's output folder when Project.exe gets built?

EDIT: I think it is important to point out, that I want to keep Project.exe and b.dll decoupled from each other. That is the point of having a.dll in the first place.

Comment: One way to do a post build event: right click on the project > properties > build > post build and you will have to write a batch command for copying a dll.

Comment: This is supposed to just work out of the box, it's how reference assembly resolution works. As such I cannot reproduce this. If a.dll has b.dll as a reference, and foo.exe has a.dll as a reference, and CopyLocal is set (both for b.dll and a.dll), both b.dll and a.dll will be copied to foo.exe's directory. So you'll have to provide more information.

Comment: Do you resolve the issue, if the issue still exists, please feel free let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try checking the Copy Local property of b.dll?

1. In Visual Studio, click on the Solution Explorer tab.
2. Find b.dll under References.
3. Right click and select Properties.
4. Make sure Copy Local is set to True.

See if that fixes it.

Comment: And, if not, add b.dll as a reference of project.exe and do the same.

Comment: Yes, Copy Local is set to true, and that doesn't help. I know that I can add b.dll as a reference to Project.exe, but I'd like to avoid that and keep these projects decoupled.

Comment: Husain's comment to your question might be the best way then.  You can use the built in variables like OutDir to copy to the bin directory as a Post-build Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use msbuild copy command to achieve it. please right click the project node -> unload project -> right click project -> edit project.csproj, add the following code on csproj file.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\b\$(OutputPath)b.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" ContinueOnError="true"/>  
  </Target>
```

Here is the sample for your reference.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgQP6j0wRMk5A1DCU

Comment: Problem with using AfterBuild is that if someone else also wants to use it it will be overridden and not executed at all. Better use e.g. AfterTargets="Build".